# Передача данных из jsp формы JAVA

Tags: java, html, jsp

Имеется jsp-страница, где создается форма для заполнения текстом и форма-кнопка, которая при нажатии должна отправлять на другую jsp содержимое первой формы:

```
<div style="width: 300px; margin: 0 auto">
<form id="add_form">
    <p class="centered" style="margin: 20px">Add Client</p>
    <label for="name">Name: </label>
    <input type="text" name="-n" id="name"/><br/>
    <label for="surname">Surname: </label>
    <input type="text" name="-s" id="surname"/><br/>
    <label for="passport">Passport: </label>
    <input type="text" name="-x" id="passport"/><br/>
    <label for="phone">Phone: </label>
    <input type="text" name="-y" id="phone"/><br/>
    <label for="account">Account: </label>
    <input type="text" name="-z" id="account"/><br/>
</form>
<div>
    <form name="AddClient" action="CommandServletView.jsp" method="get">
        <input style="width: 250px; margin: 20px" type="button" value="Add" name="Add"
               onclick="openPage('site/cmd?add&name=John&surname=Doe&passport=GF564123&phone=(067)435-1178' +
                '&account=1875635.765')"/>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function openPage(pageURL) {
            window.location.href = pageURL;
        }
    </script>
</div>
```

Если я хард-кодом пишу строку, которую хочу получить - все работает. А как передать из первой формы во вторую данные?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваша первая страница должна выглядеть так

```
<form id="add_form" name="AddClient" action="CommandServletView.jsp" method="get">
    <p class="centered" style="margin: 20px">Add Client</p>
    <label for="name">Name: </label>
    <input type="text" name="-n" id="name"/><br/>
    <label for="surname">Surname: </label>
    <input type="text" name="-s" id="surname"/><br/>
    <label for="passport">Passport: </label>
    <input type="text" name="-x" id="passport"/><br/>
    <label for="phone">Phone: </label>
    <input type="text" name="-y" id="phone"/><br/>
    <label for="account">Account: </label>
    <input type="text" name="-z" id="account"/><br/>
    <input type="hidden" name="add"/>  <!-- Дополнительное поле -->
    <input style="width: 250px; margin: 20px" type="submit" value="Add" name="Add" />
</form>
```

Comment: Спасибо, я так пробовал. Действительно, данные формы попадают куда надо. Но я не могу добиться, чтобы строка получила исполняющую команду "add". Дело в том, что заполненная форма должна добавлять все эти поля в файл. Этим управляет фреймворк. И строка должна приобрести вид: site/cmd?add&name=John&surname=Doe&passport=GF564123&phone=(067)435-1178&account=1875635.765. Как заставить строку получить эту команду, я не знаю. Может что-то подскажите?

Comment: @Alex Почему этого условия нет в исходном вопросе? Добавьте скрытое поле `<input type="hidden" name="add" />`

Comment: Точно! Забыл совсем! Спасибо!)